# the annihilator of a homogeneous ideal is homogeneous

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

> I know that if $I$ is a homogeneous ideal in $A[x]$ then $\mathrm{ann}(I)$ is also homogeneous but I don't know how to prove it.

I have tried this:

Suppose $I$ is a homogeneous ideal and take $f \in \mathrm{ann}(I)$. Then for each $g \in I$ we have $fg=0$. If $f_1,...,f_n$ are the homogeneous components of $f$ and $g_1,...,g_m$ are the homogeneous components of $g$ then $fg_i=0$ for each $i=1,...,m$. I want to show that $f_ig=0$ for each $i=1,...,n$, but that's where I got stuck.

Comment: I don't get why you are stuck: write $f$ as a sum of homogeneous components and multiply by $g_i$ which is homogeneous. This way get a sum which is zero, so every homogeneous component of the sum is zero.

Comment: I see it now, thanks.